# R: geom_abline is not starting from (0,0)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Im having a problem with a ggplot2. I've got a points plot, then I want to add abline with intercept = 0, and slope = 0.044.
Why geom_abline isn't starting from (0,0) if intercept equals 0?

Also I added black hline with xintercept = 0 and it's displayed correctly in the plot below:

[image]

Code:

```
sd.close rnorm(0,1)
avg.close rnorm(0,1)
kod letters
```

rf last point in the dataset is marked as "yes", in other case is marked as "no".

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = sd.close, y = avg.close, label = kod)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = rf), size = 4) +
  geom_text(aes(label = kod),hjust=0.5, vjust= -0.4, size = 4) +
  geom_abline(slope = a, intercept = 0, linetype = 2, colour = "red", alpha = 0.6) +
  geom_hline(xintercept = 0)
```

Comment: It could be better if we could  see the code that reproduce this weird behavior.

Comment: @SabDeM edited my question with the code.

Comment: expand your xrange to include 0, and it will look like you would expect

Comment: @nongkrong ok, how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The intercept is 0, you just can't see it on the figure because the x-axis doesnt include 0.  Expand the range of the x-axis with `xlim(0, 0.05)`.